# How to inject different NHibernate Sessions (multi-db) to same repository with Controller controlling which sessions with Ninject

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, ninject

Using: 
ASP.NET MVC3
Ninject 2
Fluent nHibernate

I have 2 databases (DB1 & DB2). I have one base repository class (Repository) and many Controllers (Controller1, Controller2).

```
public MyController(IRepository<SomeModelFromDB1> someModelFromDB1Repository, IRepository<SomeModelFromDB2> someModelFromDB2Repository)
{
    [...]
}

public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : Entity
{
    private readonly ISession _session;

    public Repository(ISessionFactory sessionFactory)
    {
        _session = sessionFactory.OpenSession();
    }
}

public class DB1SessionFactory : ISessionFactory
{
    private readonly NHibernate.ISessionFactory _sessionFactory;

    private ISession _session;

    public DB1SessionFactory()
    {
        [...]
    }
}

public class DB2SessionFactory : ISessionFactory
{
    private readonly NHibernate.ISessionFactory _sessionFactory;

    private ISession _session;

    public DB2SessionFactory()
    {
        [...]
    }
}
```

Now when I create MyController. I want my repository injected, but that repository should use DB1 (or DB2, depending on the model) SessionFactory.

I cannot figure how to properly inject it all... When I had only a single SessionFactory (DB1), here what I had with NINJECT:

```
kernel.Bind<ISessionFactory>().To<DB1SessionFactory>()
            .InRequestScope();

kernel.Bind(typeof(IRepository<>)).To(typeof(Repository<>));
```

---

Edit:

The best would be that the right session is injected in the repository depending on the model. Since some models are from DB1 and others from DB2, the choice should be dependent from it. It would be great also if the controller/view developer not have to bother with anything (like having [Named] in front of the repository) but if it's what it takes. Even with [Named], I couldn't figure how to inject the right session in the repository based on the [Named] repository in the controller...

Comment: This depends heavily on the criteria when to take which DB. Without this information it's nearly impossible to give you a good answer as there are so many ways to deal with this problem.

Comment: It ultimately depends on the model. Some models are in one DB and others are in another. It would be better if that logic would be hidden from the controller/view developer but I can't find a way to make it works. When in the controller constructor I have SomeModelDB1Repository and SomeOtherModelDB2Repository, I'd like them to have each a repository with the right session injected. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you should define the session factory in singelton scope and have the session in request scope.

Do the configuration like this:

```
.Bind<ISessionFactory>().To<DB1SessionFactory>().Named("DB1")
     .InSingletonScope();

.Bind<ISessionFactory>().To<DB2SessionFactory>().Named("DB2")
     .InSingletonScope();

private bool IsOnDB(IRequest request, string dbName)
{
    var repositoryType = request.ParentRequest.Service;
    var modelType = repositoryType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
    var databaseName = this.GetDatabaseForModel(modelType);

    return databaseName == dbName;
}

.Bind<ISession>()
    .ToMethod(ctx => ctx.Kernel.Get<ISessionProvider>("DB1").OpenSession())
    .When(r => this.IsOnDb(r, "DB1"))
    .InRequestScope();
.Bind<ISession>()
    .ToMethod(ctx => ctx.Kernel.Get<ISessionProvider>("DB2").OpenSession())
    .When(r => this.IsOnDb(r, "DB2"))
    .InRequestScope();
```

Comment: Brillant! It works great. The only problem I get is that my session gets closed before my repository have a chance to use it most of the time when I set it as InRequestScope...

Comment: Then you should think about your archtiecture. At the end of a web request all database requests should be finished. Don't use sessions over a longer time e.g. web session.

Comment: If I want to reuse the same session inside a web request(same session across different repositories for the same DB). Would The session need to be stored inside the SessionProvider as it is declared "InRequestScope"?

Comment: No. This will get you wrong results because the session provider is singleton and you would reuse the session for different web request. You will get very strange behaviors in this case. Let Ninject decide who gets which session and not the session provider.

Comment: You do not even need to implmeent an own session factory just use two correctly configured instances of NHibernate Session Factories.

Comment: I had the false assumption that SessionProvider was being called once for every repository. Ninject automagically reuse the same session when another repository is instantiated inside the same web request, which is great! Unfortunately, it defeats the purpose of having mutliple repositories using different DBs inside the same controller as the session provider won't be called again when a session is requested for a different SessionFactory.

Comment: You are right! You will need two session bindings instead of the provider. See updated answer.

Comment: Perfect! God, Ninject is beast, I'm so far from taming it! Just a note to help others who would stumble upon this solution, you should fix your answer and change the ctx.Kernel.Get<ISessionProvider> to ctx.Kernel.Get<ISessionFactory>! Thanks again.

Comment: How do you specify which session to use when trying to open one?