# How to identify what Session Ninject should bind

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, ninject

Using for the first time: Asp.NET MVC, NHibernate(FNH), DI using Ninject. I was able to get everything working with one database, but now I'm trying to use two databases (DB1 and DB2 for sake of the eg). I have a dictionary of SessionFactory(s), that is keyed by a database identifier.

I can't figure out how to select the correct Session based on what is being requested from constructor injection. I have seen this [[How to inject different NHibernate Sessions (multi-db) to same repository with Controller controling which sesions with Ninject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8262917)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8262917/how-to-inject-different-nhibernate-sessions-multi-db-to-same-repository-with-c), but I didn't get it to work.

```cs
public ProductController(DB1.Model.IRepository<Product> prodRepo, DB2.Model.IRepository<Account> acctRepo)
{
    [...]
}
```

NinjectWebCommon.cs snippet

```cs
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
{            
    kernel.Bind<ISession>().ToMethod(ctx => NHibernateSessionModule.Provider.GetCurrentSession()).InRequestScope();             
    kernel.Bind(typeof(DB1.Model.IRepository<>)).To(typeof(NHibernateRepository<>));
    kernel.Bind(typeof(DB2.Model.IRepository<>)).To(typeof(NHibernateRepository<>));
}
```

NHibernateSessionModule.cs: does UOW via Begin/End request

```cs
public class NHibernateSessionModule : IHttpModule
{        
    public static ISessionFactoryProvider Provider = new MultipleSessionFactoryProvider();

    public void Dispose() { }

    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.BeginRequest += BeginRequest;
        context.EndRequest += EndRequest;
    }

    public void BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Provider.BindNew();
    }

    public void EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Provider.Unbind();
    }
}
```

MultipleSessionFactoryProvider.cs: Not quite sure I'm doing everything here correctly.

```cs
public class MultipleSessionFactoryProvider : ISessionFactoryProvider
{
    public Dictionary<string, ISessionFactory> SessionFactories { get; private set; }

    public static Func<Dictionary<string,ISessionFactory>> InitSessionFactories = GetFactories;

    public MultipleSessionFactoryProvider() : this(InitSessionFactories())
    {

    }

    public MultipleSessionFactoryProvider(Dictionary<string, ISessionFactory> factories)
    {
        SessionFactories = factories;            
    }

    public static Dictionary<string, ISessionFactory> GetFactories()
    {
        Dictionary<string, ISessionFactory> ret = new Dictionary<string, ISessionFactory>();
        Dictionary<string, string> connectionStrings = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        connectionStrings.Add(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DB1"].Name, ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DB1"].ConnectionString.ToString());
        connectionStrings.Add(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DB2"].Name, ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DB2"].ConnectionString.ToString());

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in connectionStrings)
        {
            //Better way to do the mapping?
            ISessionFactory factory = Fluently.Configure()
            .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008.ConnectionString(pair.Value))
            .Mappings(cfg => cfg.FluentMappings.Conventions.Setup(x => x.Add(AutoImport.Never()))
            .AddFromAssemblyOf<ProductMap>())
            .BuildConfiguration()
            .CurrentSessionContext<WebSessionContext>().BuildSessionFactory();               

            ret.Add(pair.Key, factory);
        }

        return ret;
    }

    public void BindNew()
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, ISessionFactory> factory in SessionFactories)
        {
            Bind(OpenSession(factory.Key));
        }            
    }

    public void Bind(ISession session)
    {
        CurrentSessionContext.Bind(session);
    }

    public void Unbind()
    {            
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, ISessionFactory> factory in SessionFactories)
        {
            if (CurrentSessionContext.HasBind(factory.Value))
            {
                var sess = CurrentSessionContext.Unbind(factory.Value);
                sess.Dispose(); 
            }
        }
    }

    public ISession OpenSession(string factoryId)
    {
        return SessionFactories[factoryId].OpenSession();
    }


    public ISession GetCurrentSession()
    {

        string factoryId = GetIdentifier(); //<--- How to implement this

        return SessionFactories[factoryId].GetCurrentSession();
    }

    public String GetIdentifier()
    {
        return "DB1"; //Hardcoded for example

    }
```

So, how can I implement `GetIdentifier()`, or alter my Ninject binding. I did take a look at Ninject Named binding, but didn't understand how to use that when I bind the Session.

```cs
public ProductController([Name("DB1")]DB1.Model.IRepository<Product> prodRepo, [Name("DB2")]DB2.Model.IRepository<Account> acctRepo)
```

Since this is the first go around with these technologies for me, please let me know if I'm doing anything out of practice, or that might be of concern; I'd like to stay with the HttpModule.

Comment: Please, stop referring to "ASP.NET MVC" simply as "MVC". One is a framework, while other is a language-independent design pattern. It's like calling IE - "the internet"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need two bindings for session, one for each database

```
kernel.Bind<ISession>().ToMethod(ctx => GetSessionForDB1()).WhenInjectedInto(typeof(DB1.Model.IRepository<>)).InRequestScope();

kernel.Bind<ISession>().ToMethod(ctx => GetSessionForDB2()).WhenInjectedInto(typeof(DB2.Model.IRepository<>)).InRequestScope();
```